# Can't connect to my desktop folders using RStudio (python)

Tags: python, rstudio

I am using RStudio as IDE for Python (it is a requirement in my job) but I'm facing a problem. I tried to run the following code from RStudio, and it brings back an error:

```
import re

name = r"C:\Users\hoy5586\Downloads\hive_metastore.com_de_mart_mx.txn_fit_fin_preview_2024_03_12.csv"
handle = open(name)
file = handle.read()
print(file)`
```

and the error it shows is

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\hoy5586\\Downloads\\hive_metastore.com_de_mart_mx.txn_fit_fin_preview_2024_03_12.csv'
>>> file = handle.read()
>>> print(file)
```

The thing is, I have run the same code using Jupyter and it works,
I can't use Anaconda, because the connection to the datalake is through RStudio, if you are wondering.

I hope someone knows something that may help me.

Comment: you are right, I copied the error for another file I was trying, but it has nothing to do with the format of the path, for what I've been trying, it is like RStudio can't connect to my local, but I do not understand why. PS. I edited the question, thx

Comment: "it is like RStudio can't connect to my local, " Wait. Is RStudio installed locally or are you using RStudio Server or a cloud-based thing and just running RStudio in your browser?

Comment: I am using RStudio workbench, I mean, it is cloud based, I am running it in the browser.

Comment: Yes, so it is on the cloud, running in your browser. Just like a web site you connect to cannot probe your `User/Downloads` directory because of security restrictions, the IDE running in the browser cannot see your local drive's file system. You need to add things to the file system where it is running and use the code relative that. See [here](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200713893-Uploading-and-Downloading-Files-in-RStudio-Workbench-or-RStudio-Server) and run these two lines in your session to see the working directory: `import os` and `cwd = os.getcwd()`.